# Prove that function is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have got to prove that a function $$f(S, I)=-\alpha S(t) I(t)$$ is Lipschitz' continuous and then find the Lipschitz' constant.
This is all that I have got already: $$\|f(t,S_1,I_1)-f(t,S_2,I_2)\| \leqslant L(|S_1-S_2|+|I_1-I_2|)\\ |-\alpha S_1I_1+\alpha S_2I_2|\leqslant \ldots\leqslant L(|S_1-S_2|+|I_1-I_2|)$$
My biggest problem is how to modify the left side of the equation to get something that would help me prove the Lipschitz continuity and then find the satisfying constant.

Also, I was looking for books/articles where this topic was already described, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: So $S$ and $I$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @User203940 yes

Comment: Add and subtract  $\alpha S_1 I_2$ in the middle. Then you can use the triangle inequality and get terms like $\alpha \lvert S_1 \rvert \lvert I_1 - I_2\rvert$. Assuming these come from an SIR model, you can than use that $S_1$ is bounded and you get that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @User8128 so after doing as you say do I only need to write that using the triangle inequality there is a constant L that will satisfy the inequality?